# Calling AddAttachment in PHPMailer does not send mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am implementing mail utility in my PHP web application. It works fine for simple email. But if try to attach any file, send function of PHPMailer is not called i.e. mail is not sent and it is not showing any error also. Below is my sample code:

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="Email.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name = "to" id="to">
      <br>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" size="155"><br>
      <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="msg" id="msg">
      </textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Send Mail">
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
include 'library.php'; 
include "class.phpmailer.php";


$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->Port = 465;  
$mail->Username = USERNAME;
$mail->Password = USERPASS;
$mail->SetFrom(USERNAME);
$mail->Subject =$_POST['subject'];

$mail->MsgHTML($_POST['msg']);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['to']);
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"Upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    if(!$mail->AddAttachment("Upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name']))
    {
        echo "Error in attachments";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "File Attached";
    }
}
$result = $mail->Send();
echo $result;
if(!$result) {
    echo 'Error sending email' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "Email Sent";
}
```

Output of this code is following:

```
File Attached
```

After this no message is displayed and also mail is not sent from the id provided. But if I don't add any attachments it will work fine.

Comment: Have you checked your file is uploaded in Uploads ?

Comment: have you check error logs. It will give you exact cause. Also check permission.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I don't know how to check error logs can you please help me?

Comment: if you are using LAMP then you can find error log here /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: you also try this if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) { $fileName = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']; } $mail->AddAttachment($fileName);

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I tried it but it throws error: Could not access file: Desert.jpg and then email is sent without attachments and after that I tried `$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` in your code but that caused the same problem that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I have checked error logs but there is no errors in that.

Comment: Try setting `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` to get more SMTP output.

Comment: @Synchro I tried your code I got following errors:
`Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated`

Comment: Are you running an old version of PHP? PHPMailer only ever calls that function on PHP older than 5.3.0. Are you using [latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

Comment: @Synchro I have downloaded latest PHPMailer but now the same problem is coming when I am trying to send simple emails it is working fine, but when I try to attach files in it this error comes like this [Click here to see image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oaafei9ciu40k5/Email%20error.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem. Solution is I was trying to add file with 350KB which was taking more time and was throwing error of exceeded 30 sec. I just increased my time limit and problem is solved. Thank you all for helping.